# Django `sender` not working for signal receiver

Tags: django, django-signals

I am trying to create a `post_save` handler for when the model `Client` has been saved. The reason I am using a signal is because I require for the code run when a Client is added via `loaddata` as well.

Heres the sender:

```
# apps.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class ClientsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'clients'
    verbose_name = "clients"

    def ready(self):
        """https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/"""
        # Implicitly connect signal handlers decorated with @receiver.
        from . import signals
        # Explicitly connect a signal handler.
        post_save.connect(signals.write_svg, dispatch_uid="clients_client_post_save")
```

Heres the receiver:

```
# signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Client


@receiver(post_save, sender=Client)
def write_svg(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Using a signal so that when one loaddata the DB, it performs this action too"""
    print('\n-----------------------------------------------------')
    print('Signal called, sender', sender)
```

Here you can see it prints for a whole bunch of Session events, and many other events, instead of being filtered for only the client model:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Signal called, sender <class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>

-----------------------------------------------------
Signal called, sender <class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>

-----------------------------------------------------
Signal called, sender <class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>

-----------------------------------------------------
Signal called, sender <class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>

-----------------------------------------------------
Signal called, sender <class 'django.contrib.sessions.models.Session'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the

```
post_save.connect(signals.write_svg, dispatch_uid="clients_client_post_save")
```

You have already used the receivers decorator, you do not need to use the connect function too.

The first comment on your ready method explains this behaviour ;)

Comment: That comment was a copy paste from the documentation! Should have understood it better! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the signal was being registered twice. If you use the `@receiver` decorator, the line:

```
from . import signals
```

Will automatically connect the signal, you don't need to explicitly register it. The second time it was registered was with the line:

```
post_save.connect(signals.write_svg, dispatch_uid="clients_client_post_save")
```

Which does not have the `sender` filter.